# Docker startup time

Tags: performance, docker

How can I speed up: `docker run` and `docker exec` commands?

Running command takes 0.02s user time, 0.02s sys time (that would be OK in my case), but around 0.5s real time each (not acceptable).

For example:

```
$ time sudo docker run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN -i -t --memory=100000k --memory-swap=100000k -d -w /tmp -v /home/asd:/tmp my_image
187d****5037
sudo docker run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN -i -t --memory=100000k  -d -w /tmp -v    0,02s user 0,02s system 6% cpu 0,496 total
```

Can I somehow speed up process of running container or at least understand why is this time wasted?

`my_image` is created from `ubuntu` and the image built takes around 800 MB. But from what I checked it does not matter too much - reducing size image to 200 MB does not change execution time of above command.

Comment: Following @BMitch's answer, I would say `docker exec` isn't slow at all. It's mostly setup and cleanup of a container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The overhead time is most likely being spent creating and removing namespaces. To work out where the time is spent, you can run your container in different ways.

First, eliminate the sudo command. Login as root, `sudo -s`, and run commands from there.

Next try splitting the run into separate create and start steps. This will let you know if the time is spent creating the container or running it:

```
$ time docker create --cap-add SYS_ADMIN -itd \
  --memory=100000k --memory-swap=100000k \
  -w /tmp -v /home/asd:/tmp my_image

$ time docker start -ai $(docker ps -ql)
```

Since you run your container detached, consider whether you can remove the tty allocation, and if you need stdin configured, by removing the `-it`:

```
$ time sudo docker run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN -d \
  --memory=100000k --memory-swap=100000k \
  -w /tmp -v /home/asd:/tmp my_image
```

After that, you can start to look at how much time is added to create each of the namespaces for things like the network and pid by disabling them by setting them to the existing host namespace:

```
$ time sudo docker run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN -itd \
  --net=host --pid=host --uts=host \
  --memory=100000k --memory-swap=100000k \
  -w /tmp -v /home/asd:/tmp my_image
```

From docker, you can view the actions being performed with `docker events` and checking the timestamp on each of the actions.

Lastly, keep in mind that docker is a client/server application, and some of the actual time may be socket/network communication between the client and server.

Comment: Same issue as the OP. I'm running `time docker run -v "$PWD:/workdir" -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" --rm --net=none ptspts/pdfsizeopt id` on Debian 10, total time for that is 0.8s. I think it's very slow. The docker image size is <16 MB.

Comment: @pts The `--net=none` still creates a network namespace, it just limits that namespace to the loopback interface. And the other namespaces are still being created in your command.

Comment: you don't need to be root. You only need permission to read/write to the servers socket.